# Why my elements are outside their container?

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why my elements (logo, menu, info box) are outside the light grey container. Could you help me? Many thanks

See: http://jsfiddle.net/vqoudo6d/3/

[image]

HTML:

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
        <img class="header-logo" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-g-284-119-5.jpg">
        <nav class="header_nav">
            <ul class="header_nav-wrapper">
                <li class="header_nav-item">    <a id="aboutOpen" class="header_nav-item-a" href="jkk">l'Atelier</a>

                </li>
                <li class="header_nav-item">    <a class="header_nav-item-a header_nav-item-a--btn" href="jkjks" target="_blank">La Carte des soins</a>

                </li>
                <li class="header_nav-item">    <a class="header_nav-item-a header_nav-item-a--btn" href="jkjks" target="_blank">Contact</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="infos-pratiques clearfix">
        <p class="info-pratiques-tag">Informations pratiques</p>
        <div class="info-pratiques-content">
            <p>3 rue dfdsf
                <br>sdsqdssdd</p>
            <p>Lundi:
                <br>Mardi:
                <br>Mercredi:
                <br>Jeudi</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="slider">
    <ul class="slider__wrapper">
        <li class="slider__item">
            <div class="box" style="background-image:url(images/test.jpg);background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50% 50%;"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="slider__item">
            <div class="box" style="background-image:url(images/test2.jpg);background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50% 50%;"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 90%;
    height: 550px;
    background: #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    max-width: 1200px;
}
.slider__wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    *zoom: 1;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.slider__item {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    clear: none;
}
.slider__arrows-item {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.slider__arrows-item--right {
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 30px;
}
.slider__arrows-item--left {
    bottom: 50%;
    left: 30px;
}
.slider__nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
}
.slider__nav-item {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 5px;
    background: #fff;
}
.slider__nav-item--current {
    background: #ccc;
}
.slider__nav-item:hover {
    background: #ccc;
}
.box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.header {
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: absolute;
}
.header-wrapper {
    padding: 54px 60px;
}
.header-logo {
    float: left;
    clear: none;
}
.header_nav {
    float: right;
    clear: none;
    font-family:'Maven Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.header_nav-wrapper {
    list-style: none;
}
.header_nav-item {
    margin-left: 22px;
    float: left;
    clear: none;
}
.header_nav-item-a {
    color: #474032;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.header_nav-item-a:hover {
    color: #eee;
}
.header_nav-item-a--btn {
    padding: 16px 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #474032;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.header_nav-item-a--donate {
    margin-top: -18px;
}
.header_nav-item-a--btn:hover {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
 }   


    .info-pratiques-content {
        float: left;
        clear: both;
        margin-top: 14px;
        margin-left: 4.52489%;
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 1.38;
        color: #433d2b;
    }
    .info-pratiques-content p {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }
    .info-pratiques-tag {
        margin-top: 14px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        padding-top: 2px;
        padding-right: 2px;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
        padding-left: 2px;
        background-color: #9d926a;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.38;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: rgb(65, 61, 45);
    }
    .infos-pratiques {
        position: absolute;
        top: 217px;
        right: 5.1984375%;
        z-index: 26;
        width: 221px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
        opacity: 0.91;
    }
```

Comment: Too much absolute positioning...they are better layout methods [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Add border to container and you will see its size.  Or through `inspect element`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `max-width` and the `background` are on `.slider`, but your header is not inside of it.  just add the background and max-width to body and everything should be fine.

Also keep in mind that absolutely positioned elements are always relative to the closest non-static element (`position: fixed, relative, absolute`).

edit: I also agree with Paulie_D's comment, try to reduce absolute positioning

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately modifying body would have collateral impacts on my side. I tried to set a width and max-width on .header but in that case the header becomes left-aligned despite the auto-margins. Would you know why? Thanks .header {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    z-index: 999;
}

Comment: if you set something absolute, you should always at least define two positions (`top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom`)
so in your case you could add `top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;`. in combination with `margin: 0 auto;` your header would be centered. but unfortunately not in ie8 :) – but as you use a fixed width of 90% you may use `margin-left: 10%` and `margin-right:10%` to center your header instead of `auto`

Comment: of course it would be `margin-left:5%` and `margin-right:5%` :)

Comment: Thanks. One last question. How can I set a max-width of 1200px AND keep it centered horizontally? Many thanks

Comment: if ie8 is not important, use `position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; margin: 0 auto; width: 90%; max-width: 1200;` on header.
if you need ie8 support, a second conatainer is required. use absolute positioning on the outer and width, max-width and margin on inner